# Qt QODBC QSqlError Driver Error: Unable to set 'SQL_CURSOR_STATIC' as statement attribute

Tags: c++, sql, qt, odbc, qsqlquery

I have a problem executing SQL statements in my Qt program through an ODBC-Driver, the connection to the Database works fine and is not a problem.

Setup:

- (Server A) OS: Windows Server 2016 Standard
- (Server A) IDE: Qt Creator 8.0.1 (C++)
- (Server B) OS: Windows Server 2016 Standard
- (Server B) Database: ACRON Database

What is Acron:
Acron is a plant data acquisition & reports for process optimization system.

My problem:
When I send/execute SQL querys from my Qt programm on **Server A** to the the Acron Database on **Server B** via an ODBC-Driver provided by Videc(Acron), I receive the following error Message:

> QSqlError("1010", "QODBC: QODBCResult::reset: Unable to set
> 'SQL_CURSOR_STATIC' as statement attribute. Please check your ODBC
> driver configuration", [DataForum][ACRON ODBC Driver]Driver not
> capable")

What I have tried so far:
I looked into the Logfile of the Acron-Database, but there is not much usefull information to be found:

- 22.09.2022 12:29:39; INFO         ACDBComu64      ODBC Driver on Server A: Connection closed
  remote host. (10054: recv)

On the other hand, a powershell-script where I connect to the same Database and executes the same SQL-statement, just works fine ! So I'm not really sure where to look for the problem, since I didn't find anything about the SQL_CURSOR_STATIC attribute in the qt documentation I suspected it to be a Driver-Problem. Attached you will find my code:

**main.cpp** which fails to retrieve Data

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlError>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QSqlDatabase db;

    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
    db.setDatabaseName("TestDatabase101");
    //db.setConnectOptions("SQL_ATTR_ACCESS_MODE=SQL_MODE_READ_ONLY");

    if(db.open()){
        qDebug() << "Connected" << Qt::endl;
        qDebug() << db.isValid() << Qt::endl;
    }
    else
        qDebug() << "Error" << Qt::endl;

    QSqlQuery query(db);
    if(!query.exec("SELECT * FROM PV"))
        qDebug() << query.lastError() << Qt::endl;

    db.close();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**AcronConnect.ps1** Powershell-script which just works fine

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
$conn.Connectionstring = "DSN=TestDatabase101"
$conn.Open()
$sql = "SELECT * FROM PV"
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($sql,$conn)
$da = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter($cmd)
$dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$null = $da.fill($dt)
$conn.Close()
$dt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's a driver issue. It happens during the call to [SQLSetStmtAttr()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlsetstmtattr-function?view=sql-server-ver16) in QODBCResult::reset() where the third parameter can be SQL_CURSOR_STATIC.
I would ask the odbc driver vendor to fix this. Maybe debugging into QODBCResult::reset() to see the return value of SQLSetStmtAttr() can help them.

Comment: The issue has been fixed now in the newest version by the odbc Driver vendor.